# Oracle SQL: How to SELECT N records for each "group" / "cluster"

Tags: oracle

I've got a table **big_table**, with 4 million record, they are clustered in 40 groups through a column called "**process_type_cod**". The list of values that this column may assume is in a second table. Let's call it **small_table**.

So, we have big_table with a NOT NULL FK called process_type_cod that points to small_table (assume the colum name is the same on both tables).

I want N record (i.e. 10) from big_table, **for each record** of the small_table.

I.e. 
10 record from big_table related to the first record of small_table 
UNION 
10 different record from big_table related to the second record of small table, and so on.

Is it possible to obtain with a single SQL function?

Comment: Do you care which 10 rows you get for each record?  Does the result need to be deterministic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend an analytical function such as rank() or row_number().  You could do this with hard-coded unions, but the analytical function does all the hard work for you.

```
select *
from 
(
    select
      bt.col_a,
      bt.col_b,
      bt.process_type_cod,
      row_number() over ( partition by process_type_cod order by col_a nulls last ) rank
    from small_table st
    inner join big_table bt
      on st.process_type_cod = bt.process_type_cod
)
where rank < 11
;
```

You may not even need that join since big_table has all of the types you care about.  In that case, just change the 'from clause' to use big_table and drop the join.

What this does is performs the query and then sorts the records using the 'order by' operator in the partition statement.  For a given group (here we grouped by col_a), a numerical row number (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, n+1...) is applied to each record consecutively.  In the outer where clause, just filter by the records with a number lower than N.

Comment: Almost good. The analytic function RANK will produce the same number when col_a has the same value, so it's possible to select more than 10 rows per process_type_code in this query. It's better to use ROW_NUMBER in this case.

Comment: Does it make a full table acess on big table? Is it possible to avoid it? i.e. I need no sort, is there a order by null clause or something like that?

Comment: You can't avoid a sort because you are trying to aggregate based on category.  If you want to avoid a sort, you need to have a bunch of explicit union statements for each type.  As far as a full scan is concerned, it depends on how your indexes are configured.  Run the explain plan to see.